# Encryption - IV length is different than provided

Tags: java, encryption, jce

I've been struggling with encryption for a while now, and I'm about to complete the process, however, I'm now encountering some issues with the IV. Here's my code:

#### IV generation

```
public static byte[] createIV(int size) { 
 byte[] iv = new byte[size];
 SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
 random.nextBytes(iv);   

 return iv; 
}
```

#### AES-256 cipher creation (key)

```
public static Map<String, byte[]> cipherAES() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
     Map<String, byte[]> aes = new HashMap<String, byte[]>();
     aes.put("IV", ConversionUtil.toHex(createIV(16), 16).getBytes());
     KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
     keyGen.init(256);
     Key encryptionKey = keyGen.generateKey();
     aes.put("key", encryptionKey.getEncoded());

     return aes;
}
```

#### toHex method

```
public static String toHex(byte[] data, int length) {
     StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

     for (int i = 0; i != length; i++) {
        int v = data[i] & 0xff;

        buf.append(DIGITS.charAt(v >> 4));
        buf.append(DIGITS.charAt(v & 0xf));
     }

        return buf.toString();
}
```

#### Cipher initialization

```
  SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(map.get("key"), 0, map.get("key").length, "AES");
  Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
  cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(map.get("IV"), 0, 16));
```

If I provide an IV of 16 bytes with this format to the cipher:

```
8E12399C07726F5A8E12399C07726F5A
```

When I call the getIV method on the Cipher, I get this:

```
8E12399C07726F5A
```

which is exactly half the bytes I provided for the IV. This is currently causing several issues, since the server can decrypt the second part of the message but not the first one.

I'm using JCE libraries only:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
```

Can anyone shed some light on this? Let me know if you need further details.

Comment: Your problem is that you use hex digits as IV bytes. If you convert to hex, you need to undo that conversion before passing the value to your encryptor.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I'm converting them to HEX as I need to create a PEM file for the server and send it. 
   If I convert them to hex only on the pem file and then use them in the cipher without that conversion, is it acceptable?

Comment: Yes - hex-encoding for output should be a separate bit of logic. The result of `toHex().getBytes()` is essentially `String.getBytes()`, which gives you the byte representation of the hex string you created, not the bytes you put in. I.e., `"FF".getBytes()` gives you two bytes (in the default platform string encoding), not one byte. Note that other encodings (say, "UTF16") will give even different results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by [CodesInChaos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842231/encryption-iv-length-is-different-than-provided#comment19053030_13842231) and [bimsapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842231/encryption-iv-length-is-different-than-provided#comment19053743_13842231), your error lies in your conversion of the IV value into hexadecimal. A simple correction to your cipherAES() method would be:

```
public static Map<String, byte[]> cipherAES() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
     Map<String, byte[]> aes = new HashMap<String, byte[]>();
     aes.put("IV", createIV(16)); // <-- no need for conversion
     KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
     keyGen.init(256);
     Key encryptionKey = keyGen.generateKey();
     aes.put("key", encryptionKey.getEncoded());
     return aes;
}
```

Note also that your method design is a little odd. Returning a map of strings to byte arrays is quite brittle and prone to errors. Consider instead returning an object that stores these items. In that object I would store the key as a `Key`, not a byte array.

Comment: Duncan, thanks so much for your reply as well, I'm marking your answer as correct, but I also wanted to thank CodesInChaos and bimsapi. 
Regarding the design comment, you're right, it's odd, but it's not final.